# Does $S_3 \times \mathbb Z_6$ have a subgroup of order 9.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does $S_3 \times\mathbb Z_6$ have a subgroup of order $9$? where $S_3$ is the symetric group. 
Clearly $|S_3| \times |\mathbb Z_6|=36$ and $9$ does divide $36$, so its possible. But i can not figure out why or why not there would be a subgroup of order $9$.

Comment: Does $S_3$ have a subgroup of order $3$? Does $Z_6$ have a subgroup of order $3$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Both $S_3$ and $\mathbb Z_6$ have subgroups of order $3$.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about Sylow Subgroups and the existence of these. Then,  a  3-Sylow Subgroup of a group of order $36=3^2\times 2^2$ will have order $3^2=9$.